# The Compose file './docker-compose.yml' is invalid because: Unsupported config option

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have the following docker-compose file and getting this error,

```
The Compose file './docker-compose.yml' is invalid because: Unsupported config option
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3"

services:
  webserver:
    build: 
      context: ./bin/webserver
    container_name: 'png-webserver'
    restart: 'always'
    ports:
      - "81:81"
      - "444:444"
    links: 
      - mysql
    volumes: 
      - /var/www/vhost/dev.ivacy.com:/var/www/html
      - ${PHP_INI-./config/php/php.ini}:/usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
      - ${VHOSTS_DIR-./config/vhosts}:/etc/apache2/sites-enabled
      - ${LOG_DIR-./logs/apache2}:/var/log/apache2
    networks:
      vpcbr:
        ipv4_address: 10.5.0.5

  mysql:
    build: ./bin/mysql
    container_name: 'png-mysql'
    restart: 'always'
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    volumes:
      - /var/www/docker-compose-lamp/bin/mysql/db:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
      - ${MYSQL_DATA_DIR-./data/mysql}:/var/lib/mysql
      - ${MYSQL_LOG_DIR-./logs/mysql}:/var/log/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ivacy_muti_site
      MYSQL_USER: root
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: password
    networks:
      vpcbr:
        ipv4_address: 10.5.0.6
    depends_on:
     - mysql

  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    container_name: 'png-phpmyadmin'
    links:
      - mysql
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: mysql
      PMA_PORT: 3306
    ports:
      - '8081:81'
    volumes: 
      - /sessions
    networks:
      vpcbr:
        ipv4_address: 10.5.0.7
    depends_on:
     - mysql
     - webserver

  redis:
    container_name: 'png-redis'
    image: redis:latest
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
    networks:
      vpcbr:
        ipv4_address: 10.5.0.8
  networks:
    vpcbr:
      driver: bridge
      ipam:
       config:
         - subnet: 10.5.0.0/16
           gateway: 10.5.0.1
```

Comment: The `networks:` block at the end looks indented one step too many; I think that would cause this.

Comment: (You wouldn’t lose any functionality if you deleted all of the `networks:`, `links:`, and `container_name:` blocks; containers would still be able to communicate with each other using their service names as host names.)

Comment: Do you need to specify `ipam` options? This looks very hard coded and non portable. There's no way to scale it or deploy to a multi node swarm cluster. Which tool in there needs a hard coded IP address rather than the built in DNS?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You've indented `networks` into the services block.

Comment: Wouldn't `vpcbr` be the unsuppported option in this case ?

Comment: This was my issue.  I accidentally tab over the networks block which then included into the services block.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

networks should be at version level

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  web:
    build:
      args:
        version: 0.0.1
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    networks:
      - back-tier
    expose:
      - 8080
    ports:
    - 8080:8080
networks:
  back-tier:
    driver: bridge
```